# jQuery slide up two elements - one following the other

Tags: jquery, slideup

I'm trying to slide up two elements (images) one after the other at the same time - so there is no gap between the two.

I thought about using jQuery.animate(), but I couldn't figure out how to move the bottom element at the same time as the animate method is executed.

I'm assuming I'll have to use the position of the first element + its height for the moving position of the second one, but haven't got a clue how to actually make it slide at the same time as the first one.

The container for all of them has relative position and elements are positioned inside absolutely.

I just want to make a simple image / div gallery which scrolls up and don't want to use any plugins.

Any idea?

Comment: If they're "together" on the page, you could simply wrap them in a div and slide that div instead. It'll take the images along for a ride.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jYbV7/

Comment: Thanks Joseph - but that's not quite what I mean.

Comment: @user398341 can you elaborate?

Comment: Please see additional information above.

Comment: Also - Marc - thanks, but as I've mentioned - they are positioned absolutely therefore I can't have them one under another.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to or why Joseph's solution would not work, but the documentation for animate indicates that there is a function callback that you can execute after each "step" in the animation and thus updating the position of any other images you wish to move along.

Comment: Sorry, but can you try and reword your problem... it's hard to understand. E.g. a contradiction "one after the other at the same time". Also, slide up in jQuery talk generally means, hide by sliding up (http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) but trying interpret your question I think you just want to move them up...?

Comment: What I mean is to the top of the next image sticks to the bottom of the previous one and move up together until the next image reaches the top of the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a quick and dirty solution that shows how this can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/ah2zN/1/

Overflow hidden is used to prevent them from being rendered outside the slider.

Comment: Thanks Robin - that's going to do for now.